Discretization of oscillating integral
Suppose I am interested in computing
$$
I \equiv \int_0^B dx \, g(x) f(x)
$$
where $B$ is a known upper bound for the integral,
$g(x)$ is a known oscillating function and
$f(x)$ is a smooth function of which I only have
samples on a finite, discrete set of equally-spaced
points, say I know $f(x_n)$ for $x_n = a n$, with
$a$ a fixed spacing and $n = 1,\dots,N=\frac Ba$.
My question is: how can I numerically provide a good
estimate of $I$? I know that in principle, if the
function $f(x)$ was also analytically known and I
wanted to estimate $I$ numerically, I would need
to apply specific algorithms for oscillating
integrands (such as the modified Clenshaw-Curtis
technique, used in most common libraries such as
scipy).
This is why I expect the equally-spaced samples I
have access to not to be enough to provide a
well-defined procedure to correctly estimate $I$.
If you have any suggestion on either how to proceed
or what strategy/paper to refer to, it would be
very helpful. Additionally, an estimate for the
correctness of the proposed procedure, i.e. of the
corresponding error (bound) is highly encouraged.

since $f$ is smooth, you can just interpolate (say with a spline) and then proceed as usual.

Thanks, @CarloBeenakker! That was the very first idea I had as well. I have tried implementing the interpolation but it seems to lead to very poor results. I was curious whether there were other strategies viable
